# Python 3.5 I can't install Pillow

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

I have installed Python 3.5.0rc3  amd64 and I need to install Pillow. So I downloaded it from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ Pillow‑2.9.0‑cp35‑none‑win_amd64.whl and I've also installed by pip successfully. But when I'm typing in interpreter from PIL import Image I got the following message:

```
File "C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 63, in <module>
    from PIL import _imaging as core
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Moreover when I uninstalled this package and I was trying to install by easy_install I got another error:

```
Couldn't find a setup script in C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\Scripts\Pillow‑2.9.0‑cp35‑none‑win_amd64.whl.
```

What can I do?

Comment: Does this link help you? https://github.com/Alexpux/MINGW-packages/issues/237 It includes a suggestion to install openjpeg2

Comment: Please add the command you use to install pillow

Comment: Don't use a wheel: `pip install Pillow`

Comment: Why download an (unofficial) binary when you have pip installed? Have you tried `pip install Pillow` instead?

Comment: Install the [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145).

Comment: When I use pip install Pillow i got: error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: command i use to install Pillow from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/  easy_install  Pillow-2.9.0-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl

Comment: when i use pip install Pillow-2.9.0-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl installation was successfully but when i try to import is error

Comment: Thank a lot cgohlke it works

Comment: Please use Python 3.5.0 final. The RC3 has a critical bug.

Answer (score 5):

Try this command on the command line:

```
python -m pip install pillow
```